# How to observe fiber's asynchronous rendering in react16

Tags: reactjs

To my knowledge, React used a brand new Fiber architecture in version 16.
Fiber can split long tasks (5ms) to avoid React blocking the browser's main thread.
But I couldn't observe this phenomenon in the browser.

> React 16.14.0 ReactDOM 16.14.0

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```js
import React from "react";

class Commit extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const sleepTime = this.props.sleepTime;
    if (typeof sleepTime === "number") {
      const start = performance.now();
      while (performance.now() - start < sleepTime) {}
    }
    return <div>Commit</div>;
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              show: !this.state.show,
            });
          }}
        >
          switch show
        </button>
        {this.state.show &&
          new Array(200)
            .fill(0)
            .map((e, index) => <Commit key={index} sleepTime={3}></Commit>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

From `Chrome Performance`, it can be seen that React only used one Task (taking 1210ms)

> The page rendered 200 elements, each lasting 3 ms, and there was `React.StrictMode` will render twice. 200 * 3 * 2 is approximately equal to 1210ms. It's right.

[image]

And interestingly, if you switch to React18. And make some slight modifications to the code.

> React 18.2.0 ReactDOM 18.2.0

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    startTransition(()=>{
      this.setState({
        show: !this.state.show,
      });
    })
  }}
>
  switch show
</button>
```

Ohhhh.`Task split` has appeared.

[image]

1. Why React16 uses [Fiber](https://github.com/acdlite/react-fiber-architecture) and [scheduler](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/scheduler/README.md) without splitting tasks?
2. Why did React18 experience task splitting after using `startTransition`？